# Create frequency vector based on input vector

Tags: r

I have a variable test in the structure:

```
> test <- c(9,87)
> names(test) <- c("VGP", "GGW")
> dput(test)
structure(c(9, 87), .Names = c("VGP", "GGW"))
> class(test)
[1] "numeric"
```

This is a very simplified version of the input vector, but I want an output as a vector of length 100 which contains the frequency of each number 1-100 inclusive. The real input vector is of length ~1000000, so I am looking for an approach that will work for a vector of any length, assuming only numbers 1-100 are in it.

In this example, the numbers in all positions except 9 and 87 will show up as 0, and the 9th and 87th vector will both say 50.

How can I generate this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are looking for a proportion inclusive of the values that are not in the `vector` and to have those values as 0, convert the `vector` to `factor` with `levels` specified and then do the `table` and `prop.table`

```
100*prop.table(table(factor(test, levels = 1:100)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>freq<-vector(mode="numeric",length=100)
>for(i in X)
+{ if(i>=1 && i<=100)
+  freq[i]=freq[i]+1
+}
>freq
```

X is the vector containing 10000 elements
Adding an if condition could ensure that the values are in the range of [1,100].

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I had another vector X <- c(5, 67) how can I make a data frame which contains the frequency values for both data frames (test as shown above and X)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numeric vector and just want to get a frequency table of the values, use the table function.

```
set.seed(1234)
d <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace = TRUE)
x <- table(d)
x
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   
# 92  98 101 104  87 112 104  94  88 120
```

If there is a possibility of missing values, say 11 is a possibility in my example then I'd do the following:

```
y <- rep(0, 11)
names(y) <- as.character(1:11)
y[as.numeric(names(x))] <- x
y
# 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11 
 92  98 101 104  87 112 104  94  88 120   0
```